# Excel validation - can it be used to make sure duplicates are not entered?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, data-validation

I have an excel spreadsheet - is it possible to have validation so that a column cannot contain a value that already exists in the column?

Comment: @DaveParillo - aiming for the Taxonomist badge, are you ? :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, from this [example](http://exceltip.com/st/Preventing_Duplicates_While_Entering_Data_in_Excel_2007/1251.html) ...

1. Select a range of cells, for example, A2:A20.
2. Select Data -> Data Validation (in Data Tools Group).
3. In Data Validation dialog box, select Settings -> Allow -> Custom.
4. In the Formula box, enter the following formula: =COUNTIF($A$2:$A$20,A2)=1
5. Select the Error Alert tab.
6. In the Title box, enter: Duplicate Entry.
7. In the Error message box, enter: The value you entered already appears in the list 
       above.
8. Click OK.