# How to input only unique values in a column in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, worksheet-function, data-validation

I'd like to know the easiest way to make sure that only unique strings are entered in a particular column in MS Excel 2007?  I know I have to put a formula in the Data > Data Validation, but I don't know how.

Say, I'm entering data anyplace within column B, and I want to know if the inputting value is already elsewhere in the column (above or below the current cell) and don't allow if there is a duplicate.

**Edit**:

1. I've seen answers like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/11780/excel-validation-can-it-be-used-to-make-sure-duplicates-are-not-entered) on this site, but they all have an range say from B1 to B20, how do I have this validation on the entire column, is this possible?
2. Seem like when I drag on the cell, duplicated values can appear, it is only when I try to input the value that this validation works. So, how do I restrict on the dragging as well as manual input on this?

Answer (score 2):

Also, just a side note.... when referring to particular cells in a column (like in your example) you would refer to them as B1:B20. To refer to the whole column, you can use B:B. That describes an array of all data in the B column. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answered part of my question, upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

You can only deal with copying over validation with VBA:

http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/ensuring_that_data_validation_is_not_deleted/

Answer (score 0):

I answer only your question 2.
You have to write your own Private Sub Worksheet_Change routine.